# AJAX response with content-type application/octet-stream

Tags: jquery, ajax, download, blob

I have the following client-side code:

```
var downloadUrl = buildRequestUrl(); 
window.open(downloadUrl, '_self');
```

That is working fine, but I need to pass some custom headers with the request, so I am using ajax, like this:

```
$.ajax(downloadUrl, {
   headers: { 'custom-header': 'custom-header-value'},
   type: 'GET',
   contentType: 'application/octet-stream'
}).done(function (data) {
   var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
   var link = window.document.createElement('a');
   link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   link.download = '';
   link.click();
});
```

The file get downloaded, but the content is empty (3 blank pdf pages). What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: The `contentType` Ajax option in jQuery always marks the format you *send* data in. You are not sending any data in your GET request, setting the option there is useless.

Comment: Another post I found on the topic. http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/